# How to provide Internect connection via proxy server in Emulator

Tags: connection-issues, proxy

I am developing an application in my university lab.
   My lab administration provides a proxy server instead of a real internet connection to our university computers.

I don't know how to configure a proxy server with the Android emulator.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe would be better at stackexchange very slightly.

Comment: @liamwli No it wouldn't. This has nothing to do with development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see [this](http://www.rahinur.com/android-development/android-emulator-proxy-settings.html) blog post explaining how to configure APN settings to browse through a proxy.  At first, I could not believe that the APN mentioned (as TelKila) in the post will be available in my emulator. But to my surprise I find a APN is available though with a different name (as T-Mobile US).

Since I do not have a proxy server environment, I could not check and confirm this.  However the comment in the blog seems to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks lot.. after setup my proxy server Environment i can able to connect with internet..

Answer (score -1):

Very badly, there isn't a way to do this. Emulators are just like androids - no way to add a proxy, unless you use an external app, and you must be rooted to do so.

Comment: my problem is i can't able to connect with internet in emulator

Comment: I know, and I said there is no way to connect via a proxy in the emulator.